# Should VueJS re-run main.js on every route change

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

Vue.js will re-run main.js where the main Vue instance is defined every time the route changes. Is that a normal behavior?

According to vue-router documentation, only router-specific components get their content changed along with routes. However, I added a simple console log call inside the main Vue instance created hook and it gets called after every route change.

```
// main.js

import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
  created() {
    console.log('main created hook')
    this.$store.dispatch(listenToAuthChanges)
  },
  render: h => h(App),
  router,
  store
}).$mount('#app')
```

```
// /router/index.js

import Router from 'vue-router'
import routerConfig from '@/config/routes'
import { requireAuth } from './navigationGuards'

const routes = Object.values(routerConfig)
  .map(route => ({
    ...route,
    component: () =>
      import(
        /* webpackChunkName: "route.component" */
        `@/views/${route.component}.vue`
      )
  }))

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

router.beforeEach(requireAuth)
```

```html
<!-- App.vue -->

<template>
    <router-view />
</template>
```

I would expect only the content inside 'router-view' to update after every route without triggering a full app reload which causes all initial data fetching and breaks authentication navigation guards.

Comment: _"Is that a normal behavior?"_ definitely not when navigating via `<router-link>` or `$router.push()`. How are you navigating?

Comment: Thanks @Phil, I think you nailed the real problem. I am testing navigation guards changing the url through the browser url bar. I need a way to prevent loss of in-memory data in this case.

Comment: That is not possible. Every direct request results in your application running from the start

Comment: Yup. Right again. I exploring the persistent Vuex state option to have some authentication data available when url is changed through browser bar.